# How to Convert a Float Array of Samples Into a Wav File in Java?

Tags: java, android, fft, wav

I am writing an app for android that increases the volume of specific frequencies of a sound file and I unfortunately can't use the built-in Android Equalizer because I need to increase the volume on the frequencies 4kHz, 6kHz and 8kHz.

In order to do this I am reading and writing the initial .wav sound file into a float array, then performing a Fast Fourier Transform on the array, accessing the frequency band I need and increasing the volume on that band, and then finally I need to transform that array back into a .wav file for playback. The float array contains the samples of the original wav file.

I am having trouble finding a way to do this in Android Studio, this is my first time working this in-depth with sound files so I'm having trouble figuring out how to proceed.